# Marking tree file with a name

Tags: shell, awk

I have a Newick/Phylip format file as like this

```
(Chicken:0.247775,
Mouse:0.091619,
(GuineaPig:0.174006,
((OwlMonkey:0.069823,
((Chimp:0.009091,
 Human:0.009091):0.025108,
GreenMonkey:0.018831):0.015025):0.029561,
((Sheep:0.087386,
Pig:0.039886):0.022893,
Dog:0.068016):0.005950):0.023011):0.006297);
```

I need mark the the branch Dog as Dog:0.068016#Del

```
(Chicken:0.247775,
Mouse:0.091619,
(GuineaPig:0.174006,
((OwlMonkey:0.069823,
((Chimp:0.009091,
 Human:0.009091):0.025108,
GreenMonkey:0.018831):0.015025):0.029561,
 ((Sheep:0.087386,
Pig:0.039886):0.022893,
 Dog:0.068016#Del):0.005950):0.023011):0.006297);
```

This can be easily done with `sed 's/Dog:0.068016/Dog:0.068016#Del/g'`

But I have multiple files with different values and have to do multiple changes with other animals as well so I tried with following way

```
sed '/'Dog'/s/Dog/#Del/'
```

But it did not worked. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please do not format your data samples with blockquotes, use code blocks instead such that the newlines are preserved.

Comment: Why do you have so many single quotes in `sed '/'Dog'/s/Dog/#Del/'`? And you write that you "_have multiple files with different values and have to do multiple changes with other animals as well_" but you show an attempt with only `Dog` and `#Del` can you please explain a bit better what you would like to do? Where do you specify what animal, what value, what file, etc.?

Comment: I can put this code into loop, example: cat list | while read r; do sed '/'$r'/s/$r/#Del/' >$r.out; done

Comment: Please edit your question to add the missing information in the question itself such that it can be useful also for others. And please try to be consistent with the answer you accepted. Your last comment is not, for instance: do you want to take the animal names from a file or from the command line? Do you want one result file per animal or only one result file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a single call to GNU awk (for gensub() and word boundaries) to update as many targets as you like at once:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(t,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tgts[tmp[i]]
    }
}
{
    for (tgt in tgts) {
        $0 = gensub("\\<(" tgt ":[0-9.]+)","\\1#Del",1)
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -v t='Dog' -f tst.awk file
(Chicken:0.247775,
Mouse:0.091619,
(GuineaPig:0.174006,
((OwlMonkey:0.069823,
((Chimp:0.009091,
 Human:0.009091):0.025108,
GreenMonkey:0.018831):0.015025):0.029561,
((Sheep:0.087386,
Pig:0.039886):0.022893,
Dog:0.068016#Del):0.005950):0.023011):0.006297);
```

```
$ awk -v t='Dog Human Mouse' -f tst.awk file
(Chicken:0.247775,
Mouse:0.091619#Del,
(GuineaPig:0.174006,
((OwlMonkey:0.069823,
((Chimp:0.009091,
 Human:0.009091#Del):0.025108,
GreenMonkey:0.018831):0.015025):0.029561,
((Sheep:0.087386,
Pig:0.039886):0.022893,
Dog:0.068016#Del):0.005950):0.023011):0.006297);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data to modify is in a file named `myFile`, your animals are simple words (just letters), one per line, in a file named `list`, then you can do what you want in a shell loop with GNU `sed`, as you already started with:

```
cat list | while read animal; do
  sed -E 's/\<('"$animal"':[0-9.]*)/\1#Del/' myFile > "$animal".out
done
```

For each `animal` in the list a file named `animal.out` containing the modified data will be created.

The GNU `sed` command makes used of extended regular expressions (`-E`).

The regular expression to search for and substitute (`\<('"$animal"':[0-9.]*)`) starts with a beginning of word (`\<`) such that the animal name does not match anywhere in the middle of another name. The opening parenthesis starts the recording of a matching sub-expression; the closing parenthesis ends the recording. We play with single quotes and double quotes to allow the expansion of shell variable `animal` (1). Then we find a colon, followed by any number of digits or period (`[0-9.]*`).

The replacement expression uses the first (and only) recorded matching sub-expression (`\1`).

We could improve the part of the regular expression that matches the numbers following your animal names: `[0-9]*\.[0-9]*` to guarantee that it contains only one period. If you know more about these numbers we can be even more specific: `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` if you always have at least one digit before and after the period.

(1) If your animal names are really simple words the double quotes around `$animal` are useless; but it is good practice to double quote this kind of parameter expansions and it doesn't hurt.